# implementar gradiente en Vue Native

Tags: vue.js, react-native

he intentado implementar una gradiente de color en Vue Native, pero sin éxito. Intenté utilizando LinearGradient desde expo-linear-gradient, pero sin resultado. Tampoco me resulta haciéndolo en css con:

```
 background-color: linearGradient(to bottom, red, blue)
```

¿Cuál es la manera correcta para hacerlo?.